# Unable to center the image and text view in Android

Tags: android

I want to horizontally center both Image and Text View. I added `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` because I am using `Relative Layout` but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.l"
    tools:showIn="@layout/act_l">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:background="@color/switch_thumb_disabled_material_light">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/email_editText"

            />


        <EditText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/email_editText"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColorHint="#f1efef"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:minWidth="250dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/email_editText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email_editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="93dp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using `relative layout` inside a `relative layout`. I do want to change the layout. Remaining in the `relative layout`, I want to align both text fields and picture horizontally as well as vertically.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the gravity parameter in RelativeLayout? android:gravity="center"

Comment: Or android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" on your ImageView and EditText

Comment: @Joacer  
It is not working.

Comment: put your screen shot here to display what you want to do ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya Added.

Comment: you want to do like this ? @user6750923

Comment: @VishalPatoliya Like this what?

Comment: do you want to implement your code as per your screen ?above screen which u want to design >?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya Some thing similar. The basic purpose is to center all the elements horizontally inside `relative layout`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122816/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-user6750923).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/switch_thumb_disabled_material_light"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"

            />


        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/email_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:minWidth="250dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#f1efef" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/email_editText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:minWidth="250dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#f1efef"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With your suggested code. I am unable to define the width of edit text. Why is it?

Comment: remove   android:minWidth="250dp" if you not needed in edittext @user6750923

Comment: I am giving minWidth and MaxWidth to Edit text but its width is not decreasing.

Comment: remove both and define this android:layout_width="100dp" @user6750923

Comment: @Visshal. I made that by ` android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and then decrease minWidth

Comment: define with to 200dp or 100dp and remove minWidth and maxWidth property from edittext completely @user6750923

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  android:layout_centerInParent="true" in both EditText and ImageView, use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:src="@drawable/cool"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:minWidth="250dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert to a LinearLayout and then use the *gravity* of the parent to handle the vertical center.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:background="@color/myColor"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:src="@drawable/cool"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:minWidth="250dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user6750923 can you post a screenshot with the layout above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/foreground"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/foreground"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/foreground"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/foreground"
    android:onClick="clickedMe" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/foreground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="hello123"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_text"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try your code putting  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" in the ImageView, and EditText as follows and work form me. Note that I have removed some pieces of code that gave me error in the project I have tried

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@color/switch_thumb_disabled_material_light"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ai"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email_editText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColorHint="#f1efef"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:minWidth="250dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/email_editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```